# How do I configure a Magento .csv import with a custom column name?

Tags: magento, csv, import

I've got a .csv file which I need to import into a clean Magento 1.9.x instance. It has a column name which is non-standard: 'ShoeSize'

Here's the list of column names:

> "sku","websites","store","has_options","attribute_set","config_attributes","type","news_from_date","categories","name","image","small_image","thumbnail","options_container","status","visibility","price","weight","short_description","description","qty","is_in_stock","tax_class_id","ShoeSize","grouped","delivery_date","name_cas","name_fra","name_ale","description_cas","description_fra","description_ale"

When I try to import, it says:

> Column names 'ShoeSize' are invalid

Any help with solving this would be most appreciated. I've tried with custom attributes but no luck

Comment: If you can afford it, get rapid flow man.   Because Magento export/imports suck!  https://secure.unirgy.com/products/urapidflow/

Comment: thanks. i've decided to go with Prestashop instead as i find it much easier to live with, even though the .csv file is supposedly tailored to Magento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create an attribute with attribute_code `shoe_size` in your admin, and rename the column to `shoe_size`. also, make sure all attribute option values are loaded in admin.

Comment: could you please explain the last line 

"make sure all attribute option values are loaded in admin"

thanks for your help

Comment: If `shoe_size` has the following set of values: `{6,7,8,9,10}`, make sure all of those values are created in admin, for `shoe_size` attribute

Comment: thanks for your help. that's just what i needed to know for some of the other columns